# how i can switch vscode output terminal tabs use keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg63J.png)
i just want to switch those tabs use keyboard. anyone knows ,thx

i use ctrl + pagedown/pageup. but it just switch terminal tabs , not output and termial

Comment: how many of the English forum users do you think will read Chinese, show a screen shot with English GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following commands:

- **View: Toggle Problems**: (`ctrl+shift+m`) `workbench.actions.view.problems`
- **View: Toggle Output**: (`ctrl+shift+u`) `workbench.action.output.toggleOutput`
- **View: Toggle Debug Console**: (`ctrl+shift+y`) `workbench.debug.action.toggleRepl`
- **View: Toggle Terminal**: (`` ctrl+` ``) `workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal`

You could construct a collection of key bindings based on context (`when`) to call any of these commands.

Be aware that you can move/reorder the Panels, then your key bindings should change.

Or define a set of key bindings to use any sequence of 4 keys on the keyboard together with a modifier key: `ctrl+shift+alt+1` ... `ctrl+shift+alt+4`